# xcode / iphone -- invoke preprocessor only from the command line?

Tags: xcode, command-line, preprocessor, xcodebuild

Is this possible?  Basically, I want to invoke the preprocessor as if I were building my project -- but then just save the preprocessed files somewhere instead of continuing to build the whole thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here' your flag:

> ```
> -E  Stop after the preprocessing stage; do not run the compiler proper.
>     The output is in the form of preprocessed source code, which is
>     sent to the standard output.
>
>     Input files which don't require preprocessing are ignored.
> ```